# manipulate correlation parameter data in loadrunner

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am working on loadrunner using web protocol. I have captured dynamic value from server response. Before I submit the data back to the server I need to prefix \ to " ( \ shoudbe added to ").

Sample Server response:
{"clientContractDetailsId":"CCD:8a30d2d01b9c5dc3:319a2693:1562191a8e8:4e08","clientId":"0000114364","contractId":null,"clientName":"Key Safety Systems

All the " should be prefixed with \ it should become \".

Expected result:

{\"clientContractDetailsId\":\"CCD:8a30d2d01b9c5dc3:319a2693:1562191a8e8:4e08\",\"clientId\":\"0000114364\",\"contractId\":null,\"clientName\":\"Key Safety Systems

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the server response a null terminated sequence of characters?

Comment: Hi Sam, as pasted above the server response is not null. The response will be something like below...  clientContractDetailsId":"CCD:8a30d2d01b9c5dc3:319a2693:1562191a8e8:4e08","clientId":"0000114364","contractId":null,"clientName":"Key Safety Systems

Comment: Please read the my comment once more ;). What is the type in which the it is stored?

Comment: This is where your foundation skills in the language of your testing tool come into play.  Simply use C string functions to cut up your existing string using quote as a token, then reassemble using slash-quote where appropriate. #FoundationSkills_Programming